# Delete SQL values without page reload (AJAX, PHP)

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP file which shows the entries of a specific id within a SQL table. Now i want to be able to delete entries and show the updated table without a page reload.

Iam trying my best with a solution via AJAX, but no matter which entry i choose to delete, everytime only the one at the top gets deleted.

I hope someone has clue why this happens.

Here is my show.php:

```
<html>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var belegnrdel = $('#belegnrdel').val();
      var iddel = $('#iddel').val();

      $.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "del.php",
          data: { "iddel": iddel, "belegnrdel": belegnrdel},
          success: function (data) {
            $('#showtabelle').html(data);

          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
    
</html>



<?php
     
    // Includes
     
     
        require_once '../../admin/config/database.php';
        require_once '../../admin/config/dbconfig.php';
        require_once './config.php';
  
  
   echo    "<div id='showtabelle'>";        
        
 $select = $db->query("                                                         SELECT 
                                                                                belegnr, 
                                                                                gewicht, 
                                                                                id FROM 
                                                                                tabelle2 
                                                                                WHERE id='$transitnr'
                                                                                ORDER BY belegnr DESC");
        $nachrichten = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        
        $summe = mysqli_query($dbi, "                                           SELECT 
                                                                                SUM(gewicht) AS gewicht_summe 
                                                                                FROM tabelle2 
                                                                                WHERE id='$transitnr'");
        $summeausgabe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($summe); 
        $sum = $summeausgabe['gewicht_summe'];



 echo "               <div class='form'>
                                                                                <h1><b>Transitnummer:</b> $transitnr</h1>";


    

      
        echo    "           <table>
                                <thead>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <th>Belegnummer:</th>
                                                                                <th>Gewicht:</th>
                                                                                <th>Delete:</th>
                                                                            </tr>
             
                                </thead>
                                    <tbody>";



foreach($nachrichten as $nachricht) {       
        
        
        echo    "                                                           <tr>
                                                                                <td>$nachricht->belegnr<hr></td>
                                                                                <td>$nachricht->gewicht kg<hr></td>
                                                                                <td>                        
                                                                                
                                                                                <form method='post' action='' id='contactform'>
                                                                        
                                                                                    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' id='belegnrdel' value='" . $nachricht->belegnr . "'>
     
     
                                                                                    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' id='iddel'' value='" . $transitnr . "'>

    
      
                                                                                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
                                                                                    </form>  </td>";

        }
        
        echo    "                                                           </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>";
        
        echo    "                                                               <br><br>
                                                                                <b><u><align='left'>Gesamtgewicht: $sum kg </u></b>";
         
 
        echo    "</div></div>";
        
        
?>
```

This is my del.php:

```
 <html>
     
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-primary2').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var belegnrdel = $('#belegnrdel').val();
      var iddel = $('#iddel').val();

      $.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "del.php",
          data: { "iddel": iddel, "belegnrdel": belegnrdel},
          success: function (data) {
            $('#showtabelle').html(data);

          }
        });
    });
  });
  
</script>
     
     
 </html>
 
 
         <?php
         
             // Includes 

        require_once '../../admin/config/database.php';
        require_once '../../admin/config/dbconfig.php';
        require_once './config.php';
     


 if(isset($_POST["iddel"]))  
 {  
     
    $transitnr = $_POST['iddel'];
    $belegnummerdel = $_POST['belegnrdel'];
     
     
     
     echo $belegnummerdel;
     
      
 
    
        
        
        
        $query = "                                                              DELETE 
                                                                                FROM tabelle2 
                                                                                WHERE id='".$transitnr."' AND belegnr='".$belegnummerdel."'"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($dbi, $query) or die ( mysqli_error($dbi));
        
        
 }        
 
 
 
        $output = ''; 
        
        
        
        
        
        $select = $db->query("                                                  SELECT 
                                                                                belegnr, 
                                                                                gewicht, 
                                                                                id 
                                                                                FROM tabelle2 
                                                                                WHERE id='$transitnr'
                                                                                ORDER BY belegnr DESC");
        $nachrichten = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
       
        $summe = mysqli_query($dbi, "                                           SELECT 
                                                                                SUM(gewicht) AS gewicht_summe 
                                                                                FROM tabelle2 
                                                                                WHERE id='$transitnr'");
        $summeausgabe = mysqli_fetch_assoc($summe); 
        $sum = $summeausgabe['gewicht_summe'];
                                                                             
      
        
        
        
        
        
        
        $output .= " 

                    <div class='form'>
                                                                                <h1><b>Transitnummer:</b> $transitnr</h1>
      
       <table>
                                <thead>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <th>Belegnummer:</th>
                                                                                <th>Gewicht:</th>
                                                                                <th>Delete:</th>
                                                                            </tr>
             
                                </thead>
                                    <tbody>";



foreach($nachrichten as $nachricht) {       
        
        
        $output .=    "                                                           <tr>
                                                                                <td>$nachricht->belegnr<hr></td>
                                                                                <td>$nachricht->gewicht kg<hr></td>
                                                                                <td><form method='post' action='' id='contactform'>
                                                                        
                                                                                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='belegnrdel' value='" . $nachricht->belegnr . "'>
     
     
                                                                                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='iddel'' value='" . $transitnr . "'>

    
      
                                                                                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary2'>Submit</button>
                                                                                    </form>  </td>";

        }
        
        $output .=    "                                                           </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                            </table>";
        
        $output .=    "                                                               <br><br>
                                                                                <b><u><align='left'>Gesamtgewicht: $sum kg </u></b>";

                                                                                
  
    
      echo $output;  
 
 ?>
```

The show.php is included in a another file, where it gets the variables like $transitnr.

Comment: `id='belegnrdel'` ...gets output multiple times into your page, for example. But in HTML, IDs must be unique (otherwise it wouldn't be an ID, by definition!). So `$('#belegnrdel').val()` assumes that there can only be one `belegnrdel` in the page, and returns the first one it finds. All others are considered invalid. Instead, you need to find the one nearest to the button which was clicked. Either that, or just put the ID as a data-attribute of the button (much simpler) and retrieve it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use same `id` for mutliple elements instead use `class` then you can use `.closest()` and `.find()` method to get required input values and then send same to your backend.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-primary').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //get closest tr and then find inputs
    var belegnrdel = $(this).closest("tr").find('.belegnrdel').val();
    var iddel = $(this).closest("tr").find('.iddel').val();
    console.log("belegnrdel -- " + belegnrdel + " || iddel--" + iddel)
  //your ajaxcall
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id='showtabelle'>
  <div class='form'>
    <h1><b>Transitnummer:</b> $transitnr</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Belegnummer:</th>
          <th>Gewicht:</th>
          <th>Delete:</th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>12
            <hr>
          </td>
          <td>1222
            <hr>
          </td>
          <td>

            <form method='post' action='' id='contactform'>
              <!--added class-->
              <input type='hidden' class='form-control belegnrdel' value='12'>

              <input type='hidden' class='form-control iddel' value='1 '>
              <button type='submit ' class='btn btn-primary '>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1ss
            <hr>
          </td>
          <td>somethinss
            <hr>
          </td>
          <td>

            <form method='post' action='' id='contactform'>
              <!--added class-->
              <input type='hidden' class='form-control belegnrdel' value='1'>

              <input type='hidden' class='form-control iddel' value='2 '>
              <button type='submit ' class='btn btn-primary '>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```